# Visual Studio | Windows Phone Wait Without Sleep

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, wait, sleep

I was trying to wait 2 seconds before the event in my Windows Phone app. I tried `Thread.Sleep` but it stopped everything.

I am trying to wait 2 seconds but without blocking the execution of the UI thread.

Comment: Would you please stop | cramming tags in your titles | delimited | or | not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `await` an asynchronous delay with:

```
await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2000));
```

Comment: `Await Tasks.Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))`
That worked well. Thank you.